# Powering Arduino Uno, CAN Crocodile and NeoPixels from Car

Tags: arduino-uno, neopixel, can-bus

I have purchased a cigarette adapter that gives me 2 USB ports, however this gives me 5v and up to 2.4A.

Thats ok for powering the Arduino Uno, I need 12/24v to power the CAN crocodile.

I also want to drive quite a lot of NeoPixels.

How can I do this?

Comment: Being specific in your question will help; what does "quite a lot" of NeoPixels mean, in quantified terms?

Comment: Sorry, 186 neopixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reasonable estimate for current consumption of 5V NeoPixels is 60mA per pixel. For 186 pixels, that means about 11.16A at 5V; well over the 2.4A of the adapter being used for your other components.

There exist modules called "DC-to-DC Buck Converters", which can step down the 12-14V of your automobile to pretty much any voltage under the input voltage. To be safe, look for a buck converter of at least a 75W rating, and which meets your criteria for input and output range (minimum of 12V input, could be rated higher; output range inclusive of 5V.)

Be sure that the Ground connections for the NeoPixel power supply and the other supply are shared/connected, but don't share the +5V line between supplies.

Comment: Thank you, this is all a bit beyond my understanding...I'm a very good coder but electronics is something I play with...is there an off the shelf solution that I can purchase to provide me with connections suitable for the Arduino Uno with CANBus shield and the NeoPixels?

Comment: You can search the usual online vendors (amazon, ebay) for "Buck Converter" and make sure they can handle your input and output voltage needs, and at least 75W (your NeoPixels alone could draw up to 55W, and it's safe to have some buffer). Most of what you'll find are bare PC Boards with components mounted on them, but no case/enclosure. Your definition of off-the-shelf may be different.

Comment: How about this: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Droking-Converter-Step-down-Regulator-Voltmeter/dp/B07CV6QQ8Q/ref=sr_1_34_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1538492915&sr=8-34-spons&keywords=%22buck+converter%22&psc=1

Comment: That one is limited to 2A, so it won't work. In general, this community avoids direct product recommendations. On the link you gave, there are "also viewed" items that include higher-current buck converters.

Comment: I haven't worked out the current requirement, https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01N9FB78X/ref=sspa_dk_detail_1?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B01N9FB78X&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_p=8e5be0e3-b258-4b06-8b6e-695b24f935a4&pf_rd_r=ZTFR1W9099TXMBWXGJ6S&pd_rd_wg=JYlov&pf_rd_s=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_t=40701&pd_rd_w=BVivb&pf_rd_i=desktop-dp-sims&pd_rd_r=467c2bda-c656-11e8-a52e-91026566f7d5

Comment: That next link is a "boost converter" which raises output voltage *above* the input voltage. Something along these lines https://www.ebay.com/itm/24V-12V-To-5V-20A-Buck-Converter-100W-High-Current-Voltage-DC-10-35V-Regulator/223167400971

Comment: And on Amazon, although it states the output voltage is 5V: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Converter-DROK-Current-Regulator-Regulated/dp/B00F0FYPPQ/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1538494335&sr=8-1&keywords=24V+12V+To+5V+20A+Buck+Converter%2C+100W+High+Current+Voltage+DC+10-35V+Regulator

Comment: I still need at least 12v for the CAN crocodile.

Comment: Is your car not a 12V system?

Comment: Yes, its an Audi A5, I'm looking for a solution that I can plug into the power outlet in the boot, which is a cigarette lighter style socket... I need 5v for the Arduino and CANBus shield, 12v for the CAN Crocodile and 5V for the neopixels but these can draw quite a bit of current, something that protects the car system from going pop.

Comment: You don’t need a converter for the 12 V.

Comment: What I need is a convenient interface to the various voltages.

Comment: 12V from the car, 5V from the buck converter. What other voltages do you need?

Comment: Just looking for a suitable mechanical interface where I can attach all the wires...looking for something ready made I can just attach to.

Comment: I don't think you'll find something more ready-made than what has been shown so far...